# How can I retrieve the content of my jquery datatable in c#?

Tags: c#, html, jquery, datatables

I have an HTML table that I'm converting into datatable. In this datatable, I can edit a value in a cell. I want to attach a "save" button to this datatable and once a user clicks it then it should save the content of the datatable into SQL Server database.

My problem is, I couldn't find out how I can extract the data from js:datatable object into c#? I think I need to use something like below but it doesn't work and returning error.
`"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')"`. Here is the code:

```
<table id="tb_voteProjects" class="compact nowrap custom" cellspacing="0" >
            <%=getColumnHeaders()%> 
            <%=getActiveData()%> 
</table>
...

var table = $('#tb_voteProjects').DataTable({
...,
buttons: [
...
{
    text: 'Save',
    action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Ranking.aspx/SaveRanks',
            data: {table}, //HOW TO SEND THE TABLE CONTENT INTO C# ???
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function (e){
                Console.log(e);
            }
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit1: using `...data: table.rows().data()...,` instead of `...data:table...,` in my ajax didn't fix the issue.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()

Comment: @isherwood I have tried in my ajax ::> ...data: table.rows().data()... but same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dt` object in your action function - that represents the [DataTables API for your table](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.action).

From there you can use `dt.rows().data().toArray()`. This creates an array containing each row of table data in a sub-array.

You can then convert that JavaScript array to a JSON string:

```
data: JSON.stringify( dt.rows().data().toArray() ),
```

I assume you already know how to use your C# server code to retrieve the JSON payload from the body of the POST request.

---

Reference:

- [`rows().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data())
- [`toArray()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/toArray())

Comment: well, there is a progress. it gives me 500 (Internal Server Error) this time. However the method exists on the server side as [WebMethod]
        public static void SaveRanks(String tbl) { .. }

Comment: That sounds like a new question - a C# or .Net question not a DataTables question. Worth bearing in mind that the JSON string will represent an array of arrays, in your case, because of how the `<table>` is populated. (The alternative could be an array of objects, if the DataTables data is sourced in a different way). How are you deserializing that string into objects? That is probably at the heart of the new question you may want to ask (and include the server-side error in that new question, also, along with a sample of the data.)

Comment: When I try to pass no parameter, it works, otherwise gives internal server 500 error. I'll troubleshoot further and update here on monday. Thanks for your help and time

Comment: oh oh, just noticed what I missed. yes your solution works well, thank you!